# How would I copy and paste selected text using Regular Expressions and the Replace dialog in Notepad ++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Dvelving straight into the problem; all I'm trying to do here is to duplicate a line and add a bracket at the end using Regular Expressions and automate the process through the Replace With dialog in Notepad ++.

My issue visualized:

In the representation underneath, I have a bunch of instances of "["Mesh"]" that all have different path values assigned to it. All I want to do is duplicate it the path entry and add bracket at the end before the comma in the duplicated one.

What I have right now:

```
...

["Mesh"] = Platform(
     "models/ships/japan/Zuikaku.mmod",

...
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
...

["Mesh"] = Platform(
     "models/ships/japan/Zuikaku.mmod",
     "models/ships/japan/Zuikaku.mmod"),

...
```

Without getting too specific, since there are ~500 of these instances across the file I'm modifying, I do not want to go through each one while simply clicking CTRL + D to duplicate each line and add the bracket as that would take literal ages to do.

I have some limited experience with Regular Expressions from previous uses, but very limited. I know I can select the entire line in the Search dialog using ".*" but that's as far as I've gotten.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this regex (disable `. matches newline`). I am using `(\R+)` to capture end-of-line characters (and reproduce them in the output) so that it will work on systems that use other than just newline to end lines.

```
(\["Mesh"\]\s*=\s*.*(\R+))(.*),$
```

Replace with

```
$1$3,$2$3\),
```

For the input of

```
...

["Mesh"] = Platform(
     "models/ships/japan/Zuikaku.mmod",

...
```

This gives

```
...

["Mesh"] = Platform(
     "models/ships/japan/Zuikaku.mmod",
     "models/ships/japan/Zuikaku.mmod"),

...
```